# Angular Gridster: How to listen for Resizing.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gridster

I am trying to refresh a widget inside of a gridster item whenever it resizes. I can see it in the html with gridsterItem.isMoving() but I can't see this action with my controller. I have tried using their suggested js:

```
scope.$on('gridster-resized', function(sizes, gridster) {
   console.log("I'm moving")
})
```

In the html is work with:

```
{{ gridsterItem.isMoving() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside a controller,

```
 resize: function(event, $element, widget) {

     }
```

and broadcast whenever it is resized

```
  angular.element(window).on('resize', function(e){
    $scope.$broadcast('resize');
  });
```

**[`DEMO APP`](https://plnkr.co/edit/2qWdb6?p=preview)**